# Adding two CCLayers in a single CCScene side by side

Tags: iphone, ios6, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to add **two CCLayers** side by side (not one over another) on a **single scene**, with **second layer** having a **table view** on it. I have added the table view as the **subview** to the **[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view]**. The size of the second layer is that of the screen size & the size of the first layer is some what less than the size of the screen. When this screen appears, first second layer is shown. After clicking a particular button on the second layer, the scene **animates to the right** along with the table on second layer, showing the full first layer & some part of second layer.

Can anyone help me with it? I appreciate all your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has little or nothing to do with layers. A layer and its children are always drawn either on top of or behind another layer. And UIViews have no understanding of cocos2d layers or nodes at all.

What you want to do is to design the screen, then move the entire screen left or right. While moving, you need to update the table view's position accordingly every frame because it won't move along with cocos2d nodes. The CCUIViewWrapper may help but it's a little overkill if you merely want to update the view's position.

Whether you design your screen on the scene, a single or multiple layers makes no difference. In fact it's easier to use a single scene or layer because then you can animate both sides of the screen at once and in perfect synchronicity.

Comment: This was helpful. I have animated the second layer with run action & table view separately but animation for both second layer & table view are not getting synchronised...Any suggestion ...

Comment: For Layer's animation I have used the following code:  **[mHomeLayer runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.0f] two:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4f position:ccp((size.width/4)*3, 0)]]];**

Comment: And for animating table view the following code: **[UIView cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    tableViewHome.frame = CGRectMake(size.width - size.width/4,topBar.contentSize.height, size.width, size.height);
    [tableViewHome setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations ];**